# Filtering out login/logout log entries based on specific word (grep filter plugin)

Tags: fluentd

I am trying to filer out my log entries that contain a specific word.  We get tons of login and logout events in our logs and i dont want to ship those entries, i want to filter them out.  I looked into the grep filter plugin and based on the way i am understanding it it seems straight forward enough (grep message for specific word and exclude) but my setup isnt working as i am still seeing the logs entries in Splunk.

example log entry:

```
{"message":"Aug 21 09:46:15 linuxhost OSd[15]: logout(11100) usec=69895 tz=-07:00 seq=4569812 category=audit user=admin client-pid=154872 : logout"}
```

example section from my td-agent.conf:

```
<filter login.logout>
  @type grep
  <exclude>
    key message
    pattern login
    pattern logout
  </exclude>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try followings:

```
<filter login.logout>
  @type grep
  <exclude>
    key message
    pattern /login|logout/
  </exclude>
</filter>
```

Or

```
<filter login.logout>
  @type grep
  <or>
    <exclude>
      key message
      pattern /login/
    </exclude>
    <exclude>
      key message
      pattern /logout/
    </exclude>
  </or>
</filter>
```

See https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/filter_grep for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by separating out into two filters.

```
<filter ems>
  @type grep
  <exclude>
    key message
    pattern login
  </exclude>
</filter>

<filter ems>
  @type grep
  <exclude>
    key message
    pattern logout
  </exclude>
</filter>
```